# How To Print Images with PHP print function

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Please help me out. I have a form that collects picture from an upload field in a client form and the picture to be printed out on the user page. this work perfectly well on localhost and it looks like the below
Ilamini Ayebatonye Thanks A lot

```
NAME:     Name Surname

EMAIL ADDRESS:     email@provider.com

HOME ADDRESS:     123 Random Street, FakeTown

PHONE NUMBER:     012345678911

QUALIFICATION:     I.C.T Certificate

SECTOR:     CCNA

INTEREST:     please put in your interest
```

Please Print this slip, attached your C.V and photocopies of your credentials and come with it to the day of the seminar.

but the problem with is that when I uploaded the site and try registering the picture won't show again,

what i see is the below

```
ECO9JA-CREATING JOBS IN ICT
          Backgrounds_15670_zps11bc080d.png    

NAME:     Name Surname

EMAIL ADDRESS:     email@provider.com

HOME ADDRESS:     123 Random Street, FakeTown

PHONE NUMBER:     012345678911

QUALIFICATION:     I.C.T Certificate

SECTOR:     CCNA

INTEREST:     please put in your interest
```

Please Print this slip, attached your C.V and photocopies of your credentials and come with it to the day of the seminar.

THANKS FOR REGISTERING

the script is below for the image variable the form upload and the print fxn are as follows:

VARIABLE

```
<?php
$file= "file.csv";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$qualification = $_POST['qualification'];
$sector = $_POST['sector'];
$interest = $_POST['interest'];
$image= $_POST['image'];
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500">
<P>
<br>
<input type="file" name="image" value="upload" >
```

PRINT THIS CODE ON USERPAGE

```
<?php print"<img src=\"$image\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\"\/>";?>
```

Comment: Can you update your question please. And be specific in what your want.

Comment: What is the path where you upload your photo?
Also here is a resource for you: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 5):

Use this just copy and paste in your project.

```
$contents=  file_get_contents('http://localhost/elgg_social/data/36/641483447202.jpg');

$expires = 14 * 60*60*24;

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($contents));
header("Cache-Control: public", true);
header("Pragma: public", true);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expires) . ' GMT', true);

echo $contents;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem must lie when you are posting the path for the image file. I have tested the following php with an image "test.png" and it works.

```
<?php 
$image="test.png";
print"<img src=\"$image\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\"\/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is problem with your image attributes, remove "px".
it should be like this

```
<?php print"<img src=\"$image\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\"\/>";?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Uploading your photo

```
<input type="file" name="image" value="upload" >
```

It fetches the file path itself. you could move the uploaded file to your folder and the corresponding file path is to save in db.

If you are uploading the path as looks like

```
C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg
```

If you are posted as `$image = $post['image']`

Echo the path it returns to error or null

```
<img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"/>
```

If sometimes works but most time won't works as i feel this type of problem.

Thanks.

Comment: dis is not php z smtin else

Comment: _dis is not php z smtin else_ means ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the reference I commented on your php script you should have a code similar to this:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

Take a close look line by line.
You can set the maximum file size for your image upload at: `$_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000`

Furthermore this will code will make sure that the user is uploading an image and not something else.

Finally based on your need and this script after successful upload

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Then you could do this to show the image:

```
echo '<img src="upload/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"].'">';
```

Comment: do i change d ["name"] to the name on the form

Comment: Just use this in you form <input type="file" name="file" id="file" >

Comment: do i create d folder upload

Comment: i use every as u said i even create a new create d folder upload is just showing this error                                               {Invalid file}

Answer (score 0):

```
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  print $response;
```

Comment: according to the best practices on StackOverflow, you have to elaborate why this solution will help to resolve the issues from the question. Otherwise the answer will be treated as a low quality post, and might be removed. See the help section for more info.